# Односвязный список. C

Tags: c, односвязный-список

Попытался реализовать односвязный список, функции добавления элемента в конец списка,в любое место списка. Скорее всего делаю что-то не так в main(), не могу понять что. Отладчиком пользовался, аварийно вылетает при вызове функций addToEnd(....),add(..). Скорее всего ошибка глупая, заранее спасибо.

```
 typedef int type;

struct node {
    type* data;
    node* next;
};

void addToEnd(type* elem);
void add(int afterIdx, type* elem);
type* get(int idx);
void set(int idx, type* elem);

   #include "linked_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

node* first = NULL; //указатель на первый узел (Если указатель на первый элемент равен нулл это означет, что в списке нет элементов. ) 

void addToEnd(type* elem) {
    if (first) { //если указатель на первый элемент списка существует , т.е. не равен NULL)             first = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //выделяем память для указателя на первый элемент 
        first->data = elem; //присваиваем значение первому элементу 
        first->next = NULL;// присваиваем NULL т.к. не знаем указателя на следующий элемент и нам не надо с ним работать т.к. добавляем в конец
    }
    else {
        node* tmp = first; //создаем переменную ,в которой будет лежать указатель на первый элемент
        while (tmp->next) { // перебираем элементы в списке 
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        node* newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); // выделяем память для указателя на добавленный нами элемент 
        newnode->data = elem;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        tmp->next = newnode;// делаем так,чтобы предпоследний элемент указывал на наш
    }
}

void add(int afterIdx, type* elem)
{
    if (first)
    {
        first = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        first->data = elem;
        first->next = NULL;
    }
    else {

        int i = 0;
        node* tmp = first;
        while (i < afterIdx && tmp->next) //добираемся до элемента с необходимым номером 
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            i++;
        }
        node* newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //выделяем память для добовляемого узла
        newnode->data = elem;//присваиваем значени в узле 
        if (tmp->next) // если этот элемент в списке не последний выполняется условие 
        {
            newnode->next = tmp->next; //новый узел будет указывать на следующий 
        }
        else
        {
            newnode->next = NULL; //если добавляемый узел - последний элемент в списке 
        }
        tmp->next = newnode; // элемент ,который сейчас находится перед добавляемым узлом должен указывать на него 
    }

}


void set(int idx, type* elem)
{
    if (!first)
    {
        int i = 0;
        node* tmp = first;
        while (i < idx&&tmp->next)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            i++;
        }
        tmp->data = elem;
    }
    else printf("first = NULL");


}

type* get(int idx)
{
    if (!first)
    {
        int i = 0;
        node* tmp = first;
        while (i < idx && tmp->next)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            i++;
        }

        printf("Value of %i is %d", idx, tmp->data);
        return tmp->data;
    }
    else printf("first = NULL");

}

int main()
{

    int N = 0;
    int data = 0;
    printf("Input count of elements");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("Input %i element", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", &data);
        add(i,&data);

    }




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: где конкретно в функциях вылетает посмотрите, может, всё прояснится.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша первая ошибка: выражение

```
if (first)
```

эквивалентно

```
if (first != NULL)
```

а

```
if (!first)
```

эквивалентно

```
if (first == NULL)
```

Поэтому в функциях add/addToEnd/get/set Вам нужно инвертировать условия.

Вторая ошибка, что первый элемент, если его нет, нужно создавать. В функции `add` Вы это делаете, а в `addToEnd` забыли.

Таким образом, обе функции add/addToEnd должны начинаться таким кодом

```
if (!first)  // Если первого элемента нет
{
    first = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));  // то создать его
    // и проинициализировать
    first->data = elem;
    first->next = NULL;
}
```

Дальше, при заполнении списка Вы добавляете в него один и тот же указатель. В итоге, у Вас получится список из N одинаковых элементов. Поэтому заполнение списка нужно делать примерно так

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  printf("Input %i element", i + 1);
  type * data = (type*)malloc(sizeof(type))
  scanf_s("%d", data);
  add(i, data);
}
```

И последнее, на каждый `malloc()` нужно в конце работы вызвать `free()`

Comment: Спасибо,по первому и второму пункту понял ошибку.По 3 пункту тоже ошибка понятна,но как реализовать заполнение,используя разные указатели?

Comment: @oddz, очень просто: для начала посмотреть десятки аналогичных вопросов здесь, и сотни примеров - в учебниках...

Comment: Не "забыли". `malloc` в `addToEnd` присутствует. Только он "улетел" в комментарий. Аффтар просто удалил перенос строки не понимая/не замечая, что делает.

Comment: @AnT Действительно. Я так далеко вправо не крутил :)

Comment: @oddz я отредактировал ответ